# How do I show data from the saved ID in datasource C#

Tags: c#, sql, datasource

Hi I have a client table that contains ID related to information that are saved in another table to simplify the client table, i want to show in a combo box the choices possible for the user but not the ID I want to see the real information.

Example : I have a client he lives in chicago so in the city table the ID for chicago is 1.
in the client table in the columns city it will be written 1.
In the combo box i want to see chicago not 1.

For now in my project i only see the number 1 and its in a textbox not even a combo box.

I don't know if I can be clearer just ask me some question on it.

The data comes from a dataset.

Thank you

Comment: What is the target UI (e.g., ASP.NET Web Forms, ASP.NET MVC, WinForms, WPF)?

Comment: the target is WinForms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox` class inherits the `DataSource`, `DisplayMember`, and `ValueMember` properties from the `System.Windows.Forms.ListControl` class.

- `DataSource` should be assigned to the relevant `DataTable` in the `DataSet`.
- `DisplayMember` should be assigned the name of the column that contains the "real data" (i.e., the city names).
- `ValueMember` should be assigned the name of the column that contains the IDs.

See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.ListControl(v=vs.110).aspx) for the `ListControl` class for an example that uses the three properties mentioned above.

The equivalent properties for the `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl` class are:

- `DataSource` => `DataSource`
- `DisplayMember` => `DataTextField`
- `ValueMember` => `DataValueField`